# How to add array of JSON objects to Javascript array

Tags: arrays, json, object

I have an array of JSON objects that I want to create programmatically. The output array required is as follows

[image: Actual Array of JSON object required]

The current code is as follows

```
var arrData = [];
  arrData[0] = '{\"GeneralInformation\": [{\"BusinessSummary\": \"Apple Inc. designs, manufactures and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers and portable digital music players and sells a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party digital content and applications. The Company\'s; products and services include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, Apple TV, a portfolio of consumer and professional software applications, the iOS and OS X operating systems, iCloud and a variety of accessory, service and support offerings. The Company offers a range of mobile communication and media devices, personal computing products and portable digital music players, as well as a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party hardware and software products. The Company\'s primary products include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, iTunes, Mac App Store, iCloud, Operating System Software, Application Software and Other Application Software.\"},{\"Websites\": [{\"Homepage\": \"http:www.apple.com\"}]}]}';

  console.log(arrData[0]);
```

From the code above I am getting the output as below

[image: output obtained]

As we can see the output is all text. How can I output the array of JSON object as shown in first image from the code listed above.

Comment: try console.log(arrData);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you told, you have an array of JSON strings. You can simply convert it to an array of objects by applying **[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)** function to every item.

It can be easily done using **[`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** function:

```
// generates a new array by applying JSON.parse to every item
arrData = arrData.map(JSON.parse); 

// just for better understanding. "map" is almost the same as:
for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++)
{
    arrData[i] = JSON.parse(arrData[i]);
}
```

After that, `arrData` will become an array of JavaScript objects.

**Working demo:**

```js
var arrData = [];
arrData[0] = '{\"GeneralInformation\": [{\"BusinessSummary\": \"Apple Inc. designs, manufactures and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers and portable digital music players and sells a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party digital content and applications. The Company\'s; products and services include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, Apple TV, a portfolio of consumer and professional software applications, the iOS and OS X operating systems, iCloud and a variety of accessory, service and support offerings. The Company offers a range of mobile communication and media devices, personal computing products and portable digital music players, as well as a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party hardware and software products. The Company\'s primary products include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, iTunes, Mac App Store, iCloud, Operating System Software, Application Software and Other Application Software.\"},{\"Websites\": [{\"Homepage\": \"http:www.apple.com\"}]}]}';
arrData[1] = '{\"GeneralInformation\": [{\"BusinessSummary\": \"Apple Inc. designs, manufactures and markets mobile communication and media devices, personal computers and portable digital music players and sells a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party digital content and applications. The Company\'s; products and services include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, Apple TV, a portfolio of consumer and professional software applications, the iOS and OS X operating systems, iCloud and a variety of accessory, service and support offerings. The Company offers a range of mobile communication and media devices, personal computing products and portable digital music players, as well as a variety of related software, services, peripherals, networking solutions and third-party hardware and software products. The Company\'s primary products include iPhone, iPad, Mac, iPod, iTunes, Mac App Store, iCloud, Operating System Software, Application Software and Other Application Software.\"},{\"Websites\": [{\"Homepage\": \"http:www.apple.com\"}]}]}';

arrData = arrData.map(JSON.parse);
console.log(arrData);
```

```html
<div style="color: white;">Wake up Neo...</div>Look at the console
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method to parse the JSON string into JavaScript object.

```
console.log(JSON.parse(arrData[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSON.parse()](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp) converts a string in JSON format to a JavaScript object.
Since `arrData[0]` is a string, in order to access its parameters, you'd need to use JSON.parse()

```
console.log(JSON.parse(arrData[0]));
```

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Comment: @Odedra, thanks for the advice on making my answer more useful.